# Multiple servers on only 3 nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, nameserver

I've been googling for days now and I can't seem to find the answer.

I've seen multiple hosting providers with just 3 nameservers (ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com, ns3.example.com) and they have multiple shared hosting servers (web001, web002 etc)

How did they make those 3 nameservers work for all of their shared hosting servers?

Answer (score 2):

Each nameserver should be able to answer hundreds of thousands of requests per second. HTTP requests made by people browsing websites that aren't in the top 1000 wouldn't get close to a few thousands per minute or per hour.

A bit of further reading on DNS and it's evolution:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

http://www.watersprings.org/pub/id/draft-sury-deprecate-obsolete-resource-records-01.html

Answer (score 2):

DNS servers, name servers are typically separate servers not used for other services.

A name server can be used as an authoritative name server for a (practically) unlimited number of domain names.

In for example ISC Bind that would be a `named.conf` [configuration](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.14/chapter3.html) with as many "zone"  stanza's as there are domains:

```
# named.conf

... other settings:

// We are the primary server for example.com
zone "example.com" {
  // this is the primary name server for the zone
  type primary;
  file "example.com";
  // this is the default
  notify yes;
  // IP addresses of secondary servers allowed to
  // transfer example.com from this server
  allow-transfer {
    192.168.4.14;
    192.168.5.53;
  };
};

// We are the primary server for example.org
zone "example.org" {
  // this is the primary name server for the zone
  type primary;
  file "example.org";
  // this is the default
  notify yes;
  // IP addresses of secondary servers allowed to
  // transfer example.com from this server
  allow-transfer {
    192.168.4.14;
    192.168.5.53;
  };
};
```

and for each domain / zone and associated zone file containing the actual DNS records for that domain.

E.g.

```
; zone file for example.com
$TTL 2d    ; 172800 secs default TTL for zone
$ORIGIN example.com.
@             IN      SOA   ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                        2003080800 ; se = serial number
                        12h        ; ref = refresh
                        15m        ; ret = update retry
                        3w         ; ex = expiry
                        3h         ; min = minimum
                        )
              IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
              IN      MX  10  mail.example.net.
joe           IN      A       192.168.254.3
www           IN      CNAME   joe
```

---

For web hosting: the mechanism of (name based) virtual hosting is the classical way to host multiple independent websites on a single server. See for example wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting